# mobile app jquery variable results in "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Given:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone-no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
        <title>Our Application</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> <!-- added -->
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script> <!-- added -->

        <script>
            function getSearchVars() {
                var src_priceMin = 500;

                $('#form1').submit(function () {
                    src_priceMin = $("#form_priceMin").val();
                });

                var searchQuery =
                    '{' +
                        ',"priceMin":' + src_priceMin +
                    '}';

                // encode variable
                var encVar = encodeURIComponent(searchQuery);

                return encVar;
            }

            var goUrl = encodeURIComponent("http://mysite.net/api/properties?json=" + getSearchVars()) + "&callback=?";
            var searchUrl = 'http://anotherSite.com/get/?url=' + goUrl;


            $(document).on("pageinit", function(){
                $("#search").live("pageshow", function(){
                    $('#form1').submit(function() {
                        searching = true;
                        var prcMin = $("#form_priceMin").val();

                        getResults();

                        $.mobile.changePage( "#src_page", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
                        return false;
                    });
                    return false;
                });        
            });

            function init() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            function onDeviceReady() {
                // move navigator.geolocation to here later for device test
            }

            function getResults() {
                $.getJSON(searchUrl, function (data) {
                    console.log("Starting Results Fetch");
                    console.log(searchUrl);
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="home" data-role="page"  data-theme="c" data-title="Go: Home">    
            <div class="myLogo"><img src="img/go_my_logo.jpg" alt="Go my" /></div>

            <div data-role="controlgroup" id="searchField" >
                <label for="searchTitle">Find Prices:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="searchPrc" value="" placeholder="enter price" data-mini="true" />
                <img src="img/srch_btn.png" alt="search button" />
            </div> <!-- search -->


            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="vs_footer" data-theme="c">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#search" data-role="button" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- navbar -->
            </div> <!-- footer nav-->
        </div> <!-- home page -->

         <!-- search page -->
         <div data-role="page" id="search" data-theme="c">
            <div data-role="header" class="logo">
                <h1>Search</h1>
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" >
                <form id="form1">    
                    <div id="fnameDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="form_priceMin">Min. Price:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="form_priceMin" id="form_priceMin" placeholder="Enter min price" />
                    </div>

                      <div id="submitDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-inline="true"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal"></div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="vs_footer">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#search" data-role="button" data-icon="search" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Search</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- navbar -->
            </div> <!-- footer nav-->
        </div> <!-- search page -->


    <!-- Search Results--->
    <div data-role="page" id="src_page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>Search Results</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="src_content">

        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="vs_footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#search" data-role="button" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- navbar -->
        </div> <!-- footer nav-->
    </div> <!-- Search Results -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm running into is that when I submit, the value of "priceMin" in my search URL is "undefined".

Is this a scoping issue? Am I referencing the variable/form field incorrectly? The basic idea is that one would type in the Price in the Search page, click Submit, be taken to a results page displaying all things of at least that price. The purpose in the use of the URL is that I'm using an api to display "things" of a certain price. I can do it with the static value, but my call to get the value from the form field yields no data.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: you've included jquery 3 times.

Comment: Isn't it `500` rather than `undefined`?

Comment: Actually, I resolved this issue. A few salient points - I didn't include jquery 3 times. Those are 3 very different jquery files. - it wasn't "500" - the console.log() of the values was coming up quite literally as "undefined".

Anywho, the fix method was actually fairly simple. Just resolved it using input parameters in a new method that I called from the target location.